# Changing backgroundColor after hover in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I need to change hover backgroundColor in Javascript

```
function changeColor(color) {
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('kafelek');
for (var i = 0; i < block.length; i++) {
    block[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + color;
}};
```

In this code, I change color of block after click, but i need to change color of block after hover too.

```
<div class="kolorek" onclick="changeColor('2ecc71');" style="background-color:#2ecc71;"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: This code just changes the background color. When this code runs is related to how you attach this to the event. Show us the code you use to bind this to the event of some element. In general for hover check out the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events

Comment: In addition to the above comments, are you aware that background-color can be changed on hover with CSS and no JavaScript?

Comment: <element onmouseover="">

Comment: I have paletee of colors, and while im clicking one of them all blocks in other class are changing colors.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try the `mouseleave` event:

```
element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {   
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
}
```

Also if you want it to change only when the mouse is on the element, you better use css `:hover`, like so:

```
element:hover {
    background-color: #yourcolor;
}
```

Comment: But i need to dynamic change this color, so i have to use javascript